# Saving raster layer from GeoPackage results in large GeoTIFF file

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, convert, file-formats, geopackage

I have a GeoPackage file with a single raster layer and a total size of 0.5 GB that I want to convert to a GeoTIFF file. I imported the original .gpkg in QGIS and exported the one layer as a GeoTIFF, resulting in a file size of almost 30 GB (!!)

This seems quite weird to me. Can anyone explain why the .tif file is so much larger than the .gpkg? Can I reduce its size without compromising resolution and what are my other options for the file conversion?

Comment: Which extent are we talking about, which ground resolution? Why do you feel the need to export from `.gpkg` to `.tif`?

Comment: did you set any compression for the GeoTiff?

Comment: we're talking around 1000 hectars with ground resolution around 7cm. we're using an image labeling tool that only accepts geodata in `.tif` format hence the need for conversion

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the raster data in the input GPKG was compressed, while you did not set any compression when exporting the raster to GeoTIFF format. Check out the GeoTIFF format creation options: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html
and find out which compression method is appropriate for you: https://kokoalberti.com/articles/geotiff-compression-optimization-guide/.

Comment: I did indeed not set any compression! Thanks for the hint. However, chosing the highest level of compression in QGIS when exporting (and waiting around three hours) still resulted in a `.tif` file size of almost 5GB, which still is 10x the size of the original `.gpkg`..

Comment: Which exact compression options did you use? There are many nuances that can make or break a good ratio. Did you set a predictor?